# Datagridview: Create new text file if Cell value is meeting criteria

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I've created `Datagridview` as below picture with first Column as a reference value.

[image: 1]

I want to export all rows to text file based on First column value.
Every `Level=0` will create new text file with `filename= Level 0 Partnumber`

Below is my code but this code will save all data in 1 text file only.

```
SaveFileDialog sv = new SaveFileDialog();
sv.FileName = "";
sv.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
if (sv.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(sv.FileName);
    writer.Write("Level\tPartnumber\tDescription");
    writer.WriteLine("");
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            writer.Write(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString() + "\t");
        }
        writer.WriteLine("");
    }
    writer.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Data Exported");
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, you are asking the user for a filename with that `SaveFileDialog` and then you're writing all rows into that file with that given file name. No surprises here.

Comment: How many file will your picture be created?

Comment: 2 text file will be created based on the picture. Item A.txt & Item B.txt. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add linq name space and try this

```
    List<product> prdList = new List<product>();
    private void SetValue()
    {
        product prd1 = new product
        {
            Level = 0,
            PartNumber = "Item A",
            Description = "Product"
        };
        product prd2 = new product
        {
            Level = 0,
            PartNumber = "Item b",
            Description = "batry"
        };
        product prd3 = new product
        {
            Level = 1,
            PartNumber = "Item1",
            Description = "Product"
        };
        product prd4 = new product
        {
            Level = 1,
            PartNumber = "Item2",
            Description = "Product"
        };
        product prd5 = new product
        {
            Level = 1,
            PartNumber = "Item3",
            Description = "Product"
        };
        prdList.Add(prd1);
        prdList.Add(prd2);
        prdList.Add(prd3);
        prdList.Add(prd4);
        prdList.Add(prd5);
    }

    private void CreateTextFile()
    {
        var newPrdList = prdList.GroupBy(x => x.Level).ToList();

        foreach (var levels in newPrdList)
        {
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("D:\\Level" + levels.FirstOrDefault().Level + ".txt");
            writer.Write("Level\tPartnumber\tDescription");
            foreach (var level in levels)
            {
                writer.WriteLine("");
                writer.Write(level.Level.ToString() + "\t");
                writer.Write(level.Description + "\t");
                writer.Write(level.PartNumber + "\t");
                writer.WriteLine("");
            }
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
```